# show/hide panel in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a panel in user-interface called Code, I dont want to display that panel to specific users when they log in based on their roles. I am new to ExtJS. I have the algorithm/condition to block user's , but I am unsure where to apply it in this code. The .js file is:

```
analysisCodePanel = new Ext.Panel( {
    id : 'analysisCodePanel',
    title : 'Code',
    region : 'center',
    split : true,
    height : 90,
    layout : 'fit',
    listeners :
    {
        activate : function( p ) {
            GLOBAL.IDs[1] = null;
            GLOBAL.IDs[2] = null;

            p.body.mask("Loading...", 'mask-loading');
            runAll(Data, p);}
            return;
        },
        deactivate: function(){
    },
    collapsible : true                      
});
```

My condition is check whether user  is Admin so I can do `GLOBAL.IsCodeAdmin()` then show the above panel else hide it from the user logged in.

Answer (score 0):

if this panel is a child of viewport then you have  to use your controller to show and hide the panel.

In your controller put listener for viewport rendering like below. Make sure your read docs and getting started carefully. Then I'll understand how to control elements using different events. This link is a good start http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/getting_started

```
// ExtJs controller
Ext.define('app.controller.ViewPortController', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
        refs: [
            {
                ref: 'myPanel', // this elemenet can be referred as getMyPanel()
                selector: 'panel[id=analysisCodePanel]'  // selector to get panel reference
            }
        ],
        init: function () {
            this.control({
                'viewport': {
                    'render': this.viewPortRender   // on viewport render this function will be called
                }
            })
        },
        viewPortRender: function () {
            if (GLOBAL.IsCodeAdmin()) {
                this.getMyPanel().show();     // show panel
            } else {
                this.getMyPanel().hide();     // hide panel
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using an attribute for panel called disabled and setting it to true.